# Binding nested XML to CheckboxList

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a nested `xml` file which contains menu and submenus. I need to bind it to the asp.net CheckBox control on page load.

I am trying to bind using the C# code below

**C#:**

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
try
{

    //Reading the data from  the XML file
    ds.ReadXml(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/menu.xml"));
    DataView dataview = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView; 
    BioCheckBoxList.DataSource = dataview ;
    BioCheckBoxList.DataBind();            
 }
```

**XML:**

```
<menu>
  <menuItem text="Home" url="~/Default.aspx?id=e058511b-b7d9-4d39-b194-cf803014777" mid="08f360dc-   a9cf-4724-a595-66f7ca01c04e" predeficon="homeico" />
  <menuItem text="Bio" url="~/Default.aspx"  icon="~/common/theme/smoothadmin/img/cog.png">
    <subMenu>
      <menuItem text="Reg" url="~\Modules\Bio\Reg.aspx"/>
      <menuItem text="Mem" url="~\Modules\Bio\Mem.aspx"/>      
    </subMenu>
  </menuItem>

  <menuItem text="Por" url="~/Default.aspx?"  icon="~/common/theme/smoothadmin/img/cog.png">
    <subMenu>
      <menuItem text="General">
        <subMenu>
          <menuItem text="Make Appointment" url="~\Modules\Portals\Gen.aspx"/>          
        </subMenu>
      </menuItem>
    </subMenu>
  </menuItem>
</menu>
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: @JleruOHeP The problem is I don't see the node names but only System.Data.DataRowView. So the checkboxList is binded with items showing System.Data.DataRowView

Comment: You have to set 'DataTextField' and 'DataValueField' for your check box list. And I`m not suure if checkboxlist is a correct thing to use for menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use **SiteMap** instead of XML file. See here: [Using-Menu-and-Sitemap-with-Master-page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15158/Using-Menu-and-Sitemap-with-Master-page)
2. Use an **TreeView** control and bind TreeView to SiteMap.
3. In **TreeView** the **ShowCheckBoxes** property set to **All**.